# Facebook Like Button Added to My Site Not Showing Up in FB when clicked

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I added the following to my website:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="${URL}" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Every thing seems to be working with one exception.  I am allowed to add comments, but when the Post to Facebook button is clicked, nothing is showing up in Recent Activity or Likes on Facebook itself.  Is there an issue with FB?  Other things I like from other sites are appearing in Recent Activity and Likes.

Answer (score 0):

Your app id is missing in

```
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxx";
```